# how to change the Label/TextField text color Based on background image color in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm working on UIImageView with Labels and TextFields.
In my scenario, how can I change the label text color based on background image?

**For Example**: My Background image white, in that scenario the label text color is black or red except white.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if background img is black then u want label text color to be black?

Comment: No, Except black color like white or red or blue. but it will show the text

Answer (score 0):

Just engineering of answers found online:

1. Calculate average color for your background image:
   [how to find average color of image](http://www.bobbygeorgescu.com/2011/08/finding-average-color-of-uiimage/)
2. Calculate an inverted color for the found color:
   [inverting a UIColor](http://tarikfayad.com/inverting-a-uicolor/)
3. Set `label.textColor` to a result color